# How to discover devices on LAN

Tags: networking, lan, arp

I want to learn how to discover all the devices on LAN using Linux Terminal. 
I know how to ping the specific ip address,  but I'd like to learn a way that doesn't force me to ping from .1 to .255 in my LAN and how to use arping. 
If it is possible i'd like not to use Nmap, but only built-in Linux tool because where I have this LAN I have no access to Internet, so I can't download anything. 
Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes this is easy. Just log into the managed switch. If you have dumb switch then you get stuck with things like watching active traffic via arp broadcasts or using tools like nmap.

Comment: Don't you mean arping? `arping -c1 -I eth0 192.168.1.12`, and so on.

Comment: Once upon a time you could ping the broadcast address associated with the local subnet, then look at the resulting ARP table. I'm not clear if you want to do something normally trivially done with tools like ping and nmap but without using either of them for some undisclosed reason.

Comment: When I try to ping the broadcast address I get no answer, my LAN is on 192,168.2.x, so I ping 192.168.2.255 but i get no answer, maybe there is something wrong in what I do, but I don't know.

Comment: Are you really sure that the network size is `/24`? A different network size would mean a different broadcast address. You can't tell the network size from an address. You need to look at the mask assigned to your address.

Comment: Yes, I only have a /24 LAN, every sub-mask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: Ping doesn't work well, anyway, since many hosts come with a built-in firewall which will not respond to ICMP. Switch MAC address tables are the best way to find host MAC addresses. The router ARP cache would be the second best way (if you need IP addresses, too), and host ARP caches are the third best way. IPv6 is a completely different problem since it would take over 585,000 years at 1,000,000 addresses scanned per second to cover a standard `/64` subnet. IP and ethernet were never designed to do what you want, hence the tools like nmap.

Comment: Ok, you are telling me to use Nmap as I would normally do, but unfortunately I got no Internet connection there where my LAN is, and I got no way to download Nmap, this is why I was searching a way to do this with the built-in programs in Linux.

Comment: @OverMorrow: Ron is right: If you have shell access to whatever device serves as the LAN's default gateway, it's ARP table should list any recently active devices, even if they block ping (i.e. ignore ICMP echo requests). Another option is, as Ron suggests, to access the Ethernet switch - you could maybe check if you have SNMP client tools available and if the switch is SNMP capable (or has some easier interface) and find out the SNMP OIDs for the relevant info. I've no idea how long switches cache MAC address/Port data for but most devices on a LAN are pretty chatty so this is likely OK.

Comment: @Ron: Why not make your comment into an answer?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, I posted it as an answer. The reason switch MAC address tables are so good is that they are refreshed every time traffic comes into the switch port. Host ARP caches are only updated based on ARP, but switches don't use ARP, they look at every frame, and they are more likely to have current information. Unfortunately, switch MAC address tables will not have IP information since they are MAC address to port, not MAC address to IP address.

Comment: @OverMorrow, it _is_ possible to get software and data to a host which has no Internet connection. Long ago, we used floppy disks, but today, there are USB drives, CDs, DVDs, and ways to do PC to PC transfers with direct network links or Wi-Fi. Just because a PC is not connected to the Internet doesn't mean you can get a file to it.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I know , but if I could use external devices I would do as you say, but in the company I work in, we manage extra-sensible data, hence we can't bring any personal device (we are not allowed to bring our mobile phones, as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping doesn't work well, anyway, since many hosts come with a built-in firewall which will not respond to ICMP. Switch MAC address tables are the best way to find host MAC addresses. The router ARP cache would be the second best way (if you need IP addresses, too), and host ARP caches are the third best way. IPv6 is a completely different problem since it would take over 585,000 years at 1,000,000 addresses scanned per second to cover a standard /64 subnet. IP and ethernet were never designed to do what you want, hence the tools like nmap.